# Call a function in background after every half an hour in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to call a function after every half an hour in background.

Description : I have called a function in 
`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method. I need to repeat that function after every half an hour.Kindly help me to do this. Let me know if you need any details.

Comment: This app is regarding battery status.I need to update the battery status for every half an hour when it is in background.

Comment: problem is that you're not allowed to run something in background. Only if you are using (and you NEED that) stuff like described in Answer below.

Comment: ok I have used CLLocationManager.But my battery charging is decreasing very quick.So could you assist me to save the battery power

Comment: decrease accuracy and interval of your locationmanager

Comment: Unless your app  is legitimately a navigation app, this is a sure fire way to get it (and possibly anything else you've released) rejected from the app-store - either in the approval process - or later once it is released and the battery suckage becomes obvious. The apple sanctioned way of getting awoken is push notifications. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't run any `function` when your app is in `background` until your app supports these -

```
Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app

Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app

Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)

Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content

Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
```

for more details what you can do in background and how, visit -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: I like your answer.And make your answer as correct answer.I need one more help from you.i.e I have used the CLLocationManager to execute.But My battery charging is decreasing very quickly.Could you tell me to save the battery power

Comment: if you want to save your battery then you can try different desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter parameter to check which value can solve you problem. More nearest accuracy consume more power. you can also use stopUpdatingLocation when you are not using GPS to save power

Comment: Bad choice. The reason the app store guidelines are as they are is because of user-experience. Running out of battery for no obvious reason is about as bad as they get.